# Передача this в качестве параметра переменной типа родительского класса

Tags: c++, наследование

Есть класс Base. От него наследуется класс A. В методе класса A вызывается функция fun, куда передаётся указатель на объект класса A. Однако, аргументом оказывается указатель на класс Base.

**Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы аргумент object функции fun, тип которого должен быть Base,  ссылался на объект класса A?**

**Пример неправильной работы:**

Ввод: class_name

Вывод:

Class A: class_name

fun: default

**Ожидаемое поведение:**

Ввод: class_name

Вывод:

Class A: class_name

fun: class_name

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base
{
public:
    string name = "default";
};
void fun(Base* object)
{
  cout << "fun: " << object->name << endl;
}
class A: public Base
{
public:
    string name;
  A(string name) {this->name = name;};
    void fun1()
  {
    cout << "Class A: " << this->name << endl;
    fun(this);
  }
};
int main()
{
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    A a(name);
    a.fun1();
    return 0;
}
```

Ссылка на код: https://repl.it/@DmitriiNiechipo/LonelyOpulentChief

Comment: в этом плане интересно отсутствие варнингов от компилятора - это меня удивило

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Повторная декларация `name` в классе наследнике прячет от кода наследника родительский член класса. До родительского `name` можно добраться, но подозреваю, что Вам нужно просто убрать `string name;` из `A`.

```
class A: public Base
{
public:
    //string name;
```